# Condtion varible even when notified can't get out of std::condition_varible.wait(), but sometimes it can?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I have a while loop which is **constantly** locking & unlocking a mutex

```
while(true)
{
    mtx.lock();
    mess_with_global_data();
    thread_opener(); 
    // ^^^
    // this opens a thread at random times. If a thread is already open then it checks to see 
    // if it is done, if so close it. 
    mtx.unlock();
    cv.notify_all();
}
```

keep in mind that the varibles are global.
The thread_opener function, puts this function on a thread:

```
void foo()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> unique_mtx(mtx);
    cv.wait(unique_mtx); // this is where it gets stuck, sometimes it is able to get through
    if(some_global_var == 5)
    {
        some_global_var--;
    }
    unique_mtx.unlock();
}
```

The issue/problem:
The conditon varible - even when notified in another
thread, it does not lock the mutex ***everytime***.
instead it takes a few seconds or even a few minutes
before the condtion varible can finally lock
the mutex.

I think the problem is that the main thread is locking
the mutex before the child thread can lock it it-self.
But shouldn't the wait method be the very first one
to lock it? And if the problem was the main thread locking
the mutex too quick, how do I stop it? and instead choose
the other thread that was waiting?

EDIT, code for thread_opener():

```
void thread_opener()
{
    // foo_thread is ptr to a std::thread object allocated on the heap
    if(!foo_thread && (rand() % 5) == 3)
    {
        foo_thread = new std::thread(&foo); 
    }
    else if(foo_thread->joinable())
    {
       foo_thread->join();
       delete foo_thread();
       foo_thread = nullptr;
    }
}
```

Comment: One problem here is that the notification may take place before the other thread starts waiting in `foo`. For more detailed analysis, you would have to provide the code of `thread_opener` function.

Comment: @DanielLangr, even if I add a check for the notification to only send a notification when there is a thread active - the problem still persists. But I guess it is one of many. I will provide the code for thread_opener()

Comment: That the thread is active does not mean it has started waiting.

Comment: @DanielLangr hmm.. . is there anyway to check if a condtion varible is waiting?

Comment: Not directly. That's why a condition variable is practically always used together with an additional flag. The example is right here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable.

Comment: @DanielLangr I'll make a atomic boolean flag , and use that to indicate that the thread is waiting. I'll keep this open in case it does not work

Comment: I'd say the issue here is a race condition.  The scope of your mutex in the main loop is far too broad, as there appears to be no reason to keep the mutex locked while trying to join on the thread.  If your loop manages to pick up the mutex again before the other thread manages to receive the notification and re-lock the mutex, then your `thread_opener` function is going to block execution while holding the mutex.  This will cause deadlock.

Comment: As is, this is a perfect example of a deadlock. Consider the following possible ordering of operations: 1) main thread creates a new thread which runs `foo`, 2) main threads unlocks the mutex, 3) main thread calls `notify_all`, 4) other thread locks the mutex, 5) other thread calls `wait` which unlocks the mutex internally, 6) main thread calls `join` inside `thread_opener`. Consequently, the main thread is blocked at `join` and the other thread is blocked at `wait`, and there is nothing that would stop any of these.

Comment: Gosh... if only I'd thought of that... ;)

Answer (score 0):

this came from: @DanielLangr.
As is, this is a perfect example of a deadlock. Consider the following possible ordering of operations: 1) main thread creates a new thread which runs foo, 2) main threads unlocks the mutex, 3) main thread calls notify_all, 4) other thread locks the mutex, 5) other thread calls wait which unlocks the mutex internally, 6) main thread calls join inside thread_opener. Consequently, the main thread is blocked at join and the other thread is blocked at wait, and there is nothing that would stop any of these. –

Helped me with developing a solution:
the solution being adding a flag(boolean) that the thread is done at the end of foo(). and check that instead of checking with std::thread::joinable().

Comment: I just identified the problem but did not suggest any solution. Which would make the answer incomplete. That's why I just wrote a comment about this issue.